# Create manual page break within tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I am wanting to insert a new page within a [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) environment but the following example shows it ignores the `\newpage` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{activitybox}{%
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=white,
    title={\bfseries Title}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{activitybox}
    \lipsum[1]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1]
\end{activitybox}

\end{document}
```

The documentation suggests the only way to do this is create a [fake break (page 373)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=373) where I create two separate `tcolorbox` environments between the `\newpage` command with the skin parameters set to `skin=enhancedfirst` and  `skin=enhancedlast` respectively.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{activitybox}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=white,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{activitybox}[title=Title,skin=enhancedfirst]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{activitybox}
\newpage
\begin{activitybox}[skin=enhancedlast]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{activitybox}

\end{document}
```

The trouble with this idea is the new page might need to get placed within environments. These will then have to be closed prematurely and opened again while making sure the environment state is continued from before. There may also be further beginning and ending definitions within those environments that shouldn't be called since the environment has not truly ended and is still continuing over the page.

An alternative solution is to make use of the `break at` [(page 355)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=355) parameter which will break the `tcolorbox` at a given length. This is unusable in my situation since the number of `tcolorbox` environments goes into the hundreds with each edit of the document needing a recalculation of each `break at` parameter which in turn is only possible after a full render of the document to be able to measure the new length by hand.

At a lower level a page break is possible when `breakable` [(page 351)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=351) is enabled and the `tcolourbox` environment needs to span more than one page. Is it possible to fire that page break at a higher level or at least fill in the rest of the page with blank vertical space?

Comment: I don't think this will work with `\newpage` -- A `tcolorbox` content is read into a box register and the total height of the box (i.e. height and depth) is measured -- if this is too large for the page, the box is broken (if `breakable` has been enabled). However, `\newpage` does not really add extra spacing such that the box would get too high, so `\newpage` can't trigger a break

Comment: Do you think it is possible to fire that same page break at a higher level or at least fill the rest of the page with blank vertical space so one is triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{activitybox}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=white,
    #1
}
\newcommand*{\fakebreak}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}\pagebreak}


\begin{document}

\begin{activitybox}[title=Title]
    \lipsum[1]

    \fakebreak

    \lipsum[1]
\end{activitybox}

\end{document}
```

But note, that the result is different, because the box will be filled to the page end!

If you want similar behaviour for automatic breaks, use option `height fixed for=first and middle`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{activitybox}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=white,
    #1
}
\newcommand*{\fakebreak}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}\pagebreak}


\begin{document}

\begin{activitybox}[title=Title,height fixed for=first and middle]
    \lipsum[1]

    \fakebreak

    \lipsum[1-2]
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[3-4]}% \parbox used to force an early page break
    \lipsum[5-7]
\end{activitybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume there isn't a parameter that ensures the border is displayed right to the page end when a `breakable` box is continued over the page? Just to ensure a consistency in style.

Comment: @ADarkDividedGem  See `height fixed for=first and middle` in the manual.