# How to force mdframed / tcolorbox height to be pageheight across multiple pages?

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed

I have noticed, when using `mdframed` and `tcolorbox`, that it is difficult to force the box to stretch to be exactly the height of the page.

Furthermore, the use of `newpage` and `pagebreak` does not work well with `tcolorbox`, although it does seem to work with `mdframed`.

How can I achieve a multi-page coloured box to hold content that is forced to be the height of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350324/146362), I believe the easiest way to do it is to use `tcolorbox` with two smart custom commands:

```
\newcommand*{\fakebreak}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}\pagebreak}
\newcommand*{\fakefill}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}}
```

- `fakebreak` allows you to fill the page and then induce a page break (although the next page will not have forced pageheight).
- `fakefill` lets you force the box to have a height equal to that of the page (minus margins) without inducing a page break.

That gives you output like this, which is what you want, I think:

[image]

Unfortunately, if you are particular about using `mdframed` and not `tcolorbox`, I have not found a way to force that.

---

Code for the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
parbox = false,
colback = white, colframe = black,
left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in,
height = \textheight,
sharp corners,
boxrule = 1pt,
breakable
]

\newcommand*{\fakebreak}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}\pagebreak}
\newcommand*{\fakefill}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners,thick, fill, fill opacity = 0.2] (-0.2,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\fakebreak


\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners,thick, fill, fill opacity = 0.2] (-0.2,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\fakefill

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```